# Access time in Real time

Tags: python, loops, time

I am trying to have a loop run for the first 45 seconds of every minute with the below code. However when I obtain the seconds the variable is only storing what the second value is at that exact time. How can I make the variable constantly update every second?

My code:

```
i = time.strftime("%S")
print i   

while i < 45:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a continuous loop printing each second as a countdown timer:

```
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
import time

while True:
    if not datetime.now().second: # make sure we start first run at start of minute
        t = timedelta(seconds=45)
        while t:
           t -= timedelta(seconds=1)
           time.sleep(1)
           print(t)
        time.sleep(15) # sleep for 15 seconds before starting again
        t = timedelta(seconds=45)
```

If you don't care about the first start time and want to count up:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

while True:
    for sec in iter(lambda: datetime.now().second, 46):
        print(sec)
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(14)  # sleep for 14 seconds before starting again

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
..............
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.time()` will give you your time in seconds since midnight.

```
import time
current_time = time.time()
time.sleep(6) #Delay Deliberately
print time.time() - current_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Pretty but I got it to work as follows:

```
c = 1

while c < 2:
        i = float( time.strftime("%S"))
        while i < 30:
           i = float(time.strftime("%S"))
```